# Exporting table parameter result as .txt file using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, export, export-to-text

Is there a way that I could use for me to export the table parameter into .txt file in SQL Server?

Sample code that I did for trying to print out the

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (fld_Name VARCHAR(12), fld_Number VARCHAR(11))
DECLARE @fileTimeStamp varchar(200) =  convert(varchar,getDate(), 112 )+'_'+ Replace(convert(varchar,getDate(), 114 ),':','')  -- select convert(varchar, getdate(), 121)
DECLARE @fileExtension varchar(5) = 'txt'

INSERT INTO @testTable
SELECT [fld_Name] AS fld_Name,
        [fld_Number] AS fld_Number
FROM TableBA tblBA
INNER JOIN TableCAS tblCAS ON
tblCAS.fld_Code = tblBA.fld_AccountNumber
WHERE [fld_Name] NOT IN (SELECT [fld_Name] FROM TableLeads)

declare @fn varchar(500) = 'D:/Test/Leads_'+@fileTimeStamp+'.'+@fileExtension;
declare @cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', @testTable, ' > "', @fn, '"');
print @cmd 
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output

set @cmd  = concat('type "', @fn, '"');

print @cmd 
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Using that gives me an error of:

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@testTable"

Is there a way that I could print the `SELECT *` results from the table parameter I created?

Comment: Using your approach - no. Echo will simply dump a string to stdout - which you then redirect to a file. I don't think this is a feasible approach to export a complete table. So I think now is a good time to step back and reconsider the decisions leading to this path. And note that there is no "datatable" here as most interpret the term. I suggest you search the internet for "export from table to file"

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
    declare @tablename varchar(100)='@testTable'
    DECLARE @fileTimeStamp varchar(200) =  convert(varchar,getDate(), 112 )+'_'+ Replace(convert(varchar,getDate(), 114 ),':','')  -- select convert(varchar, getdate(), 121)
    DECLARE @fileExtension varchar(5) = 'txt'
    
    EXEC ('DECLARE '+@tablename+' TABLE (fld_Name VARCHAR(12), fld_Number VARCHAR(11)) ;
    INSERT INTO '+@tablename+'
    SELECT [fld_Name] AS fld_Name,
            [fld_Number] AS fld_Number
    FROM TableBA tblBA
    INNER JOIN TableCAS tblCAS ON
    tblCAS.fld_Code = tblBA.fld_AccountNumber
    WHERE [fld_Name] NOT IN (SELECT [fld_Name] FROM TableLeads);
    ')
    declare @fn varchar(500) = 'D:/Test/Leads_'+@fileTimeStamp+'.'+@fileExtension;
    declare @cmd varchar(8000) =  concat('echo ', @tablename, ' > "', @fn, '"');
    print @cmd
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, i tried using it but the one that was printed is **@testTable** which is the one set in the @tableName parameter.

Comment: Yes,Here we are passing table name as parameter value. Bcoz in your query you assigned table variable name to scalar variable so SQL Server Confused.Due to this i used scalar variable to pass table variable name

Comment: Hello, but my goal is to export the results from the created table there.